# How to check an underlying async Task.Result result for null

Tags: c#, .net, async-await, task-parallel-library

### Background

Currently I have a .NET Core 3.1 WebAPI method that is communicating with a SOAP service asynchronously. When I run my task and get a response it usually works, but sometimes the SOAP service will send an 200 Ok() with an empty response. This is wreaking havoc for me. How can I check that the underlying Result/GetSomeFancyDataResult is null?

Because GetSomeFancyDataResult is a result under the "Result", I am getting a valid "Result" but "GetSomeFancyDataResult" is null and when I try to check it for null, *I get an error that it's not instantiated.*

### Example Code

```
    // make an async request to legacy SOAP service
    var client = new mySoapService.serviceClient();
    var request = new mySoapService.GetSomeFancyDataRequest(1, "abc", 234);
    var task = Task.Run(async () => await client.GetSomeFancyDataAsync(request));

    // how to check if GetSomeFancyDataResult exists ?
    if (task.Result.Equals(null) || task.Result.GetSomeFancyDataResult.Equals(null))
        return null; // exit here, abort!

    // process the results when data is found in the result ??
    var results = task.Result.GetSomeFancyData.Select(result => result.MyFancyFieldOne);
```

### My Problem

My problem is that this doesn't work as expected...

```
// how to check if GetSomeFancyDataResult exists ?
if (task.Result.Equals(null) || task.Result.GetSomeFancyDataResult.Equals(null))
    return null; // exit here, abort!
```

Maybe I have stared at this for too long. What am I overlooking here? I have searched SO and the interwebs and haven't found how to check this for null correctly. Help?

Comment: Have you tried `if (task.Result == null || etc.)`.  Calling `task.Result.Equals(null)` seems wrong.  If you look at the example `object.Equals` override here https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.object.equals?view=netframework-4.8, it checks for `null`, but that doesn't seem to be something I'd count on

Comment: Just a sec... If `task.Result` is null, then `task.Result.Equals(null)` should throw a null ref exception.  Is that the _doesn't work as expected_ behavior you are seeing?

Comment: It's also worth noting that calling `.Result` on otherwise `async` code can cause self-deadlock: https://blog.stephencleary.com/2012/07/dont-block-on-async-code.html.  I'd take @nkosi's advice if I were you

Comment: @Nkosi: um, no.  If `task.Result` is null, then `task.Result.Equals(null)` (the first condition in the `if`) is equivalent to `null.Equals(null)`.  Unless `.Equals` is implemented as an Extension method (which I'm pretty sure it isn't), that will throw

Comment: @AussieJoe - Try not to get discouraged. Some people will downvote even when a question is well written.

Comment: @Flydog57 note that OP uses Core which does not deadlock for the same reason as regular .NET - there is no more synchronization context - https://blog.stephencleary.com/2017/03/aspnetcore-synchronization-context.html
…

Comment: @AussieJoe please do not vandalize your own post by making it no longer a question by including answer. You are welcome to post an answer as answer. If you believe that post should be deleted you have to flag for moderator attention and explain why it must be deleted.

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov both solutions work, one is cleaner but wasnt posted as answer. Sorry, was just trying to get it in there before it's closed by downvoting sharks,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Consider just awaiting the result and perform your check on the returned value.

```
// make an async request to legacy SOAP service
var client = new mySoapService.serviceClient();
var request = new mySoapService.GetSomeFancyDataRequest(1, "abc", 234);
var result = await client.GetSomeFancyDataAsync(request);

//check if GetSomeFancyDataResult exists
if (result == null || result.GetSomeFancyDataResult == null)
    return null; // exit here, abort!

// process the results when data is found in the result ??
var results = result.GetSomeFancyData.Select(x => x.MyFancyFieldOne);
```

Comment: this worked. I have been staring at it too much and too long. Thank you!

Comment: Good opportunity for null coalescing operator also.  `if (result?.GetSomeFancyDataResult == null)`

Comment: Or, assuming that last line was supposed to be the same property and was just typoed, you can skip the if and just `return result?.GetSomeDancyDataResult?.Select(result => result.MyFancyFieldOne);`

Comment: @MattJohnson-Pint oh, that's hot!!

Comment: @Nkosi actually this does not work if I change my await. If I keep it like in my example, it does work. Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

Using @Matt Johnson-Pint's suggestion works cleanest for me.

```
// make an async request to legacy SOAP service
var client = new mySoapService.serviceClient();
var request = new mySoapService.GetSomeFancyDataRequest(1, "abc", 234);
var task = Task.Run(async () => await client.GetSomeFancyDataAsync(request));

// process the results when data is found in the result ??
var results = task.Result?.GetSomeFancyData?.Select(result => result.MyFancyFieldOne);

if (results == null)
    return null;

return results;
```